# TextMate Live Preview of GFM (GitHub flavored Markdown)

Tags: textmate, textmatebundles, github-flavored-markdown

I found [TextMate support for GitHub flavored Markdown](https://github.com/streeter/markdown-redcarpet.tmbundle)

http://github.github.com/github-flavored-markdown/

and now try to install (lots of ruby stuff needs to be installed, struggling..)

then will try to have live preview feature.

Perhaps, it is possible with a shortcut key, but is it possible on every modification without saving the file?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to make a preview without file saving, just run `Bundles > Markdown Redcarpet > Preview` or here is a shortcut for this: <kbd>⌃</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>.

To use a keyboard shortcut properly, I recommend to uninstall original `Markdown` bundle.

Comment: Thank you. Now I use SublimeText and develop my own Markdown Live edit plugin.